# Keyboard Robot class issue

Tags: java, awtrobot

I've created Keyboard class for working with Robot. But when I starting using methods from this class I have error in logs.

Here's my `Keyboard.java` with method `pressEscape()`:

```
public class Keyboard {

    private static Robot robot;
    private static int time = 1000;

    public Keyboard(){
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   public void pressEscape() throws TestException {
        if (!getSession().CanRun())
            throw new TestException(InvalidStateMessage);
        robot.delay(time);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
        robot.delay(time);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
        robot.delay(time);
    }

}
```

And here's error from log:

> [2015/08/13 15:43:29] [ID:7F4315A] [Selenium]: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   [2015/08/13 15:43:29] [ID:7F4315A] [Selenium]:    at Kodak.AutoTest.Framework.Keyboard.pressEscape(Keyboard.java:128)

Change a little method:

```
public void pressEscape() throws TestException {
        if (!getSession().CanRun())
            throw new TestException(InvalidStateMessage);
        try {
            new Robot();
            robot.setAutoDelay(time);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);     
            robot.setAutoDelay(time);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

but still has the same error on line:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

Comment: what is the line 128 in your code? Where do you get function `getSession()` ?

Comment: You shouldn't be maintaining `static` reference to the fields for the class, unless you intend to make it a utility class and make the methods `static` as well

Comment: You can also use [`Robot#setAutoDelay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#setAutoDelay(int)) which `Robot` will use between executing commands

Comment: 182 line is:
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

Comment: It's line 128, not 182, that it was reporting.

Comment: oh, rsy it's not 182, robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE); - is on 128 line

Comment: setAutoDelay didn't help, has the same error on line - robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

Comment: Can you update with your imports?

Comment: Post answer, now it's working fine

Comment: @JasonP. it's simply not possible for it to throw a NPE in that line at the top level of the stack, unless `robot` is null, and the only way that can happen at that point in your code is if another thread has set it to null.

Comment: @JasonP. in your updated code the line `new Robot()` doesn't do anything useful because it doesn't assign the result to anything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the only place you can realistically get a null pointer exception in that method is in this line:

```
if (!getSession().CanRun())
```

which will throw a NPE if `getSession()` returns `null`. Actually the other option is if you failed to initialise `robot`, but then you'd be seeing an `AWTException` in the logs.

But you should confirm this by looking at the line number that the logs gave you. If this is right, I'd suggest changing

```
if (!getSession().CanRun())
            throw new TestException(InvalidStateMessage);
```

to

```
Session session = getSession();
if ((session==null) || !session.CanRun())
            throw new TestException(InvalidStateMessage);
```

That will harden that part, and mean you'll get a `TestException` if the session is null. (I am guessing the type that `getSession()` returns.)

Additionally, although you are initialising `robot` in your constructor, you should be aware that it's a static field. That means that if you have lots of `Keyboard` instances, every time you create an instance, it'll overwrite the previous instance of `robot` with a new one, because they all share the same one.

You should either change it to an instance field (remove the `static` modifier), or initialise it only once (check if it's null, and initialise it only if so).

Comment: I've another Java classes, and all of them working fine with this. And session is not null.

Answer (score 0):

For this to happen your `robot` variable should be null at line 128. This can happen only `new Robot()` threw an exception. Check your logs to see whether it is the case. And also see comments to your questions from MadProgrammer and act on them.

Comment: was trying this: 
public void pressEscape() throws TestException {
     if (!getSession().CanRun())
            throw new TestException(InvalidStateMessage);
     try {
   new Robot();
   robot.setAutoDelay(time);
      robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);     
      robot.setAutoDelay(time);
      robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
  } catch (AWTException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
     
    }
and has the same error on  line: robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

Comment: You should have added as code to the original question. Atleast in the pasted code, I don't see `new Robot()` being assigned to `robot`.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, here's full code:

```
public class Keyboard {

    private static Robot robot;

   public void pressEscape() throws TestException {
    if (!getSession().CanRun())
        throw new TestException(InvalidStateMessage);
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.setAutoDelay(time);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);     
        robot.setAutoDelay(time);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```